# Como setar um valor default criado pelo usuário na criação de uma tabela (SQL Server)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Eu criei um valor default para o meu banco de dados:

```
CREATE DEFAULT [dbo].[zero] as 0
```

Porém não consigo criar uma tabela utilizando desse valor default criado. Como faço para setar esse valor na hora da criação de uma tabela? Por exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE TESTE ( num int DEFAULT zero)
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode definir o valor *default* do campo "num" ao criar a tabela TESTE assim:

```
CREATE TABLE TESTE
(
    num int DEFAULT (0)
)
```

Esse recurso "CREATE DEFAULT" será removido em uma versão futura do *Microsoft SQL Server* conforme **[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173565.aspx)**, então é bom evitá-lo.

Comment: Então, mas a ideia seria de aproveitar o default zero pra outras tabelas também, aí caso algum dia eu queira mudar o valor eu mudaria direto no default e isso replicaria pra todas as tabelas. O zero neste caso foi mais para um exemplo, mas valeu.